# Probability and mathematical statistics

Tags: probability

> Consider the function
>   $$
> f(x) = \begin{cases}
> C \left(2x-x^{3/2}\right), & 0 \le x \le 3\\
> 0, & \text{otherwise}
> \end{cases}
> $$
>   Could $f$ be a probability density function? If so determine $C$, and do the same problem for
>   $$
> f(x) = \begin{cases}
> C \left(2x-x^2\right), & 0 \le x \le 3\\
> 0, & \text{otherwise}
> \end{cases}
> $$

Comment: Take a [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) of the site to see how to ask a good question.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics! Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say what your thoughts on this problem are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Answer (score 2):

HINT :

Is $f(x)\geq 0$ ? If yes, what is $\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb R}f$ ? What is the conclusion ?

Comment: Sorry not g(x). Second aslo f(x)